# Can't map route to action, ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on Web API project and have the following problem:

I have tried to call the action method called 'GetUserBy' with the following Url (https://localhost:44328/api/Users/GetUserBy?username=myusername&password=mypassword), but the result I received in the browser looks like this:

```
{"id":["The value 'GetUserBy' is not valid."]}
```

Below is my UsersController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{

    // GET: api/Users
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        //this works
        //code removed for simplicity
    }

    //GET: api/Users/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser([FromRoute] int id)
    {
       //this works too
    }

    [HttpGet("Users/GetUserBy")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserBy([FromQuery]string username, [FromQuery]string password)
    {
        //this doesn't work
    }
}
```

when I insert the breakpoint on this method, code execution never seems to come there regardless I call it or not.

I added the following code in startup.cs file, but nothing has changed.

```
 app.UseMvc(
            routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("GetUserBy", "{controller=Users}/{action=GetUserBy}");
            }
            );
```

I have also visited the following web page, but I can't find the answer.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: try changing your Tag from this: `[HttpGet("Users/GetUserBy")]` to this: `[HttpGet("GetUserBy")]`, you already have it routing to the Controller by name Users

Comment: I have tried it so many times and didn't work and now it works :)

Comment: @Ryan Wilson, thank you. I knew that something simple was..

Comment: You're welcome. Have a good day! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing your Tag from this:

```
[HttpGet("Users/GetUserBy")]
```

to this:

```
[HttpGet("GetUserBy")]
```

you already have it routing to the Controller Users

Answer (score 2):

You are experiencing route conflicts.

```
api/Users/GetUserBy
```

matches this route

```
//GET: api/Users/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser([FromRoute] int id)
{
   //this works too
}
```

but it is treating the `GetUserBy` string in the URL as the `{id}` in the route template.

Since `"GetUserBy"` is not an `int` you get that invalid value error message.

add a route constraint so that it will only match for an integer.

```
//GET: api/Users/5
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser([FromRoute] int id) {
   //...
}
```

The current `GetUserBy` action has `Users/GetUserBy` as its route template, which would resolve to `api/Users/Users/GetUserBy` given the current `api/[controller]` route template on the controller.

Consider using the action token to get the desired behavior.

Here is the completed code with the changes suggested above.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase {

    // GET: api/Users
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers() {
        //...
    }

    //GET: api/Users/5
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser([FromRoute] int id) {
       //...
    }
    //GET: api/Users/GetUserBy
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserBy([FromQuery]string username, [FromQuery]string password) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: brackets around an action method gave me InvalidOperationException error and double brackets  - the same problem I had..

Comment: @A.M take a look at the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area

Comment: InvalidOperationException: The following errors occurred with attribute routing information:
 
 Error 1:
 For action: 'DDDDService.UsersController.GetUserBy (DDDDService)'
 Error: While processing template 'api/[controller]/[Users]/[GetUserBy]', a replacement value for the token 'Users' could not be found. Available tokens: 'action, controller'. To use a '[' or ']' as a literal string in a route or within a constraint, use '[[' or ']]' instead.